# DNS A Records Disappear On Multi-NIC Server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-server-2016, vlan, windows-server-2019

I have a 2 Servers running as a top Level DCs on a Parent Domain. They are running DNS for the following addresses.

```
192.168.1.X (DHCP) 
192.168.10.X (Static)
```

I have 2 servers running as child level DCs on a Child Domain. They are running DNS for the following Address

```
192.168.2.X (DHCP)
```

I have 1 File server joined to the top level domain but connected to the 3 networks at the following addresses:

```
192.168.1.10 (DHCP)  (DNS Servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2)
192.168.2.10 (DHCP)  (DNS Servers 192.168.2.1, 192.168.2.2)
192.168.10.10 (Static)  (DNS Servers 192.168.10.1, 192.168.10.2)
```

The issue I am having is that the A record in DNS is missing in the child DNSs. And the top level DNS has the record (192.168.2.10) for the 192.168.2.X domain. The DHCP is supposed to point at 192.168.2.1 ad 192.168.2.2 which is the child domain.

Also the other 2 DNS records for 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.10.10 are missing from the top level DNS Servers. I have tried to manually add them and they stay for a few hours and then disappear. Why this keeps happening or how to fix this because when people  on the child or parent domains with the same address as the missing records they can't UNC to the server?

Comment: Is scavenging enabled on the DNS Servers?

Comment: @Davidw I am not sure. How do I check. What does scavenging do?

Comment: Scavenging is removing stale DNS records. Right click on the individual DNS Server in the DNS management console and in the pop up menu, click on scavenging/aging configuration, there should be a check box to enable/disable scavenging stale records.

Comment: @Davidw thanks I will check it out

Comment: @Davidw no scavenging is not turned on.

Comment: Have you checked the DNS logs?

Comment: @Davidw No. Event log DNS logs or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the event log.

Comment: @davidw It just deleted 4 records I manually made this morning

Comment: Now you have a time frame to look for the logs.

Comment: @Davidw What Event am I looking for? Mostly I have 5502 for a non Windows System.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to simply review the logs to see if  there's anything that stands out.

Comment: @Davidw I updated the question with more information. Logs having shown anything.